# Converting HTML format to the BBCode format of Mobile Legends

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, fonts

I’m currently working on a creative in-game text app for the game **Mobile Legends**. The app can change the text color you use while chatting in-game. There are also other additions like bold, italic, underline and strike through, with the final output being a code for you to input. The app is designed to be user friendly and quick to use. However, I’m having trouble with the creative aspects.

**The site:** https://mlcolor.netlify.app/

I made my own rich editor that uses `execcommand`. I need a solution that converts HTML format (that the rich editor produces) into Mobile Legends text format.

### The Mobile Legends format

It is the same as with HTML. Instead of `<b>Hello World</b>` it uses brackets `[b]Hello World[/b]`

**These are the formats in Mobile Legends which are very similar with HTML:**

Bold: `[b]Hello World[/b]`

Italic: `[i]Hello World[/i]`

Underline: `[u]Hello World[/u]`

StrikeThrough: `[s]Hello World[/s]`

foreColor: `[FF0000]Hello World` *it uses hex code.*

### The Problem

How do I convert this code (example output):

> ***<strike>Hello World!</strike>***

```
<b><i><u><strike>Hello World!</strike></u></i></b>
```

in to this:

```
[b][i][u][s]Hello World![/b][/i][/s]
```

### My solution

I used a method using `.replace(/<b>/g,'[b]')`. However if the format gets too complicated, the harder is to replace the tags. The code gets complicated and has many attributes.

**Example of a complex format:**

> *Lo***rem** ipsu**m** *dolor* sit <strike>**amet***.*</strike>

```
<span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><font color="#a9fcd4"><i>Lo</i><b>rem</b></font></span> <i style="text-decoration: underline;"><font color="#0000cc">ipsu<b>m</b></font></i> <b style="text-decoration: underline;"><i><font color="#cc00cc">dolor</font></i></b> <u><font color="#cccc00">sit</font></u> <strike><font color="#cc00cc"><b>amet</b><i>.</i></font></strike></span><br>
```

> Disclaimer: I’m not a professional coder by any means so I apologize
> for any amateur mistakes. Coding is just my spare time hobby and I
> decided to make this app for the Mobile Legends community since I play
> the game too and wanted to decorate my bio and chat text.

Comment: Is the list of the "Mobile Legends" possible formats complete? This question is to prevent that an answer will get the comment "ah good, now I also need to convert background color as follows, and also linespacing, and also alignment, and also..."

Comment: Thanks for answering. The list of possible formats is already complete. No more addition. Thank you!

Comment: How is plain text escaped when it has special characters like `[` in them?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this question. I didn’t really consider that possibility before this. It’ll show up in plain text if they put special characters because I haven’t coded for that part yet. As for now, special text isn’t allowed in my app. I’ll put an in-app sign saying so. 

Thanks again. This made me see a hole in my app that I didn’t consider before.

Comment: How long does a color setting remain valid (since there is no corresponding end tag)? For instance `[b][FF0000]This[/b] test`. Is "test" still red?

Comment: (2) Is there a mapping for tags like `<br>` and `<p>`?

Comment: There's none. Only for bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, and forecolor.

Comment: See also my preceding comment.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no end tag for foreColors in mobile legends. Therefore, `[FF0000]This[/b] test`. "test" is still red.

Comment: OK, I will soon post an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help especially since I was having a really hard time and kept coming up with dead ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the input with a DOM parser. Then walk through that DOM recursively, and check the style of each visited node to determine which tags and colour should be specified. Here is how that could work:

```js
function parse(html) {
    let appliedColor = "000000";
    
    function parseNode(inheritedStyles, inheritedColor, node) {
        // Base case: a plain text node:
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            if (inheritedColor !== appliedColor && node.nodeValue.trim()) {
                appliedColor = inheritedColor;
                return `[${appliedColor}]${node.nodeValue}`;
            }
            return node.nodeValue;
        }
        // Transfer color HTML attribute to style attribute:
        if (node.nodeName === "FONT" && node.color) node.style.color = node.color;

        // Get relevant styles of this node
        let {color, textDecorationLine, fontWeight, fontStyle} = node.style;
        color = color || inheritedColor;

        // Determine U,S,B,I:
        let styles = {
            u: inheritedStyles.u || node.nodeName === "U" || textDecorationLine.includes("underline"),
            s: inheritedStyles.s || node.nodeName === "STRIKE" || textDecorationLine.includes("through"),
            b: inheritedStyles.b || node.nodeName === "B" || fontWeight.includes("bold") || +fontWeight >= 700,
            i: inheritedStyles.i || node.nodeName === "I" || fontStyle.includes("italic")
        };
        
        // Deal with color
        if (color.slice(0,4) === "rgb(") {
            color = color.match(/\d+/g).map(dec => (+dec).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("").toUpperCase();
        }

        // Apply recursion to parse the child nodes
        let res = Array.from(node.childNodes, parseNode.bind(null, styles, color)).join("");

        // Wrap the content inside the necessary [] tags
        for (let prop in styles) {
            if (styles[prop] !== !!inheritedStyles[prop]) res = `[${prop}]${res}[\/${prop}]`;
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    return parseNode({}, "000000", new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html").body);
}

// Demo
let html = `<span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><font color="#a9fcd4"><i>Lo<\/i><b>rem<\/b><\/font><\/span> <i style="text-decoration: underline;"><font color="#0000cc">ipsu<b>m<\/b><\/font><\/i> <b style="text-decoration: underline;"><i><font color="#cc00cc">dolor<\/font><\/i><\/b> <u><font color="#cccc00">sit<\/font><\/u> <strike><font color="#cc00cc"><b>amet<\/b><i>.<\/i><\/font><\/strike><\/span><br>`;

console.log(parse(html));
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for giving me the answer! It really worked. I really appreciate your help- it was such a hard thing for me to try and code. As a beginner, I’m really in awe of how you solved this problem. It was great learning from you! Again, thank you a thousand times.